# Minimum permissions required for a SQL Server user account

Tags: windows, sql-server

I have a sql server user named `SchoolTeacher` to access my
application.

It has the following rights to my `PrimarySchool` database

> INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, CONNECT, SELECT

The user must be able to perform simple DB operations through my c# application (ADD,SEARCH, UPDATE, DELETE)

I have tested the application, and these permissions seem enough, still it's good to have a second opinion.

Are these permissions enough or do I need to add/reduce some more ?

Comment: I'd say this belongs here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If it satisfies the working of your application in entirety, it should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user needs to execute some SP (Stored Procedure), you need to give him/her executor role. Here how you can do it;

```
USE [MyDatabaseName]
GO

/* CREATE A NEW ROLE */
CREATE ROLE db_executor;

/* GRANT EXECUTE TO THE ROLE */
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor;
```

Then you need to simple add your user to `db_executor` role. It will allow him/her to exec SPs from your app.

But your title seems that you need to give the user as low permission as possible so this action might not be needed if you are not working with SPs.

On the other hand, if you have dependencies on other database (for example your companies Master database named Contoso.Master), you need to grant permissions to your user to do some stuff on those dbs as well.

Comment: The user is able execute SPs with the current permission set.

Comment: oh, I didn't see that. You have already given EXECUTE permission